# Dictionary up to date

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

This is my script...

```
shop = ["Apple" , "orange", "mangoo" , "Tomato" , "grape"]
dict = {}
#List Shop

x = """
1. apple
2. orange
3. mangoo
4. tomato
5. grape """
print x
#Screen showing in monitor

while True:

    buy = int(raw_input('what do u want to buy?" (use number 1-7): '))
    buy = shop[buy-1]
    print "You want" , buy
    equal = int(raw_input('how much? : '))
    bb = {buy:equal}
    dict.update(bb)
    print dict, x
```

If I chose same order. old values will change with newest values...

I want make it, like this...

I choose "Apple" and I want to Buy "3"

in the next command I want to buy "Apple" again

but I'll buy "6".
So equal for the apple is "9"...

Note : python 2.7 , this method without using zip, def, return and break option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: `dict` is reserved keyword for dictionary. use something like my_dict.

try this:

```
my_dict[buy] = my_dict.get(buy, 0) + equal
```

Syntax of dict.get:

```
dict.get(key[,default])
```

code:

```
shop = ["Apple" , "orange", "mangoo" , "Tomato" , "grape"]
my_dict = {}
#List Shop

x = """
1. apple
2. orange
3. mangoo
4. tomato
5. grape """
print x
#Screen showing in monitor

while True:    
    buy = int(raw_input('what do u want to buy?" (use number 1-7): '))
    buy = shop[buy-1]
    print "You want" , buy
    equal = int(raw_input('how much? : '))
    my_dict[buy] = my_dict.get(buy, 0) + equal
    print my_dict, x
```

Comment: @Helonder777 I update the whole code, see my updated post